# Perl IPC without using shared memory?

Tags: linux, perl, ipc

Part of the code is:

```
sub _getPages {
    my $self      = shift;
    my $rel_url   = lc(shift);
    my @turls     = ();
    my $urls      = [];
    my $ipc_share =  tie $urls, 'IPC::Shareable',undef, { destroy   => 1 };

    foreach my $stag (@{$self->{SUPP_TAGS}}) {

           push(@{$urls}, map { lc($self->_normalizeSupportURL($_->url(),
                                                             $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->uri->authority,
                                                             $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->uri->scheme)) }
                              grep { ((index($_->url,$rel_url) > -1) || ($_->url =~ m{^/})) &&
                                     $_->url !~ m/answer|mailto:/i }
                        $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->find_all_links( text_regex     => qr/$stag/i ),
                        $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->find_all_links( name_regex     => qr/$stag/i ),
                        $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->find_all_links( url_abs_regex  => qr/$stag/i ));
    }
    @{$urls} = uniq(@{$urls});

    foreach my $url (@{$urls}) {

        if (!exists($self->{UNQ_URLS}->{lc($url)}))  {
            $self->{UNQ_URLS}->{lc($url)} = 1;

            $self->{SUPP_PROC}->start and next;
            if (eval {$self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->get($url); } ) {
                push(@{$urls}, map { lc($self->_normalizeSupportURL($_->url(),
                                                                  $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->uri->authority,
                                                                  $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->uri->scheme)) }
                             grep { ((index($_->url,$rel_url) > -1) || ($_->url =~ m{^/}) ||
                                      $_->url =~ m/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/ ) &&
                                      $_->url !~ m/answer|mailto:/i }
                             $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->find_all_links( text_regex     => qr/chat/i ),
                             $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->find_all_links( name_regex     => qr/chat/i ),
                             $self->{MECH_O}->getGlobalMechInstance()->find_all_links( url_abs_regex  => qr/chat/i ));
            }
            $self->{SUPP_PROC}->finish;
        }
    }
    $self->{SUPP_PROC}->wait_all_children;

    return uniq(@{$urls});
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to do, is to share the `$urls` between the processes, so I can add urls to it, but I keep getting:

> Could not create semaphore set: No space left on device

which is something to do the kernel (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) parameters (SEMMNI,SEMMNS).
I Increased them, but its still doesnt really useful, so I probably doing something wrong here.

It there another way (Probably `Storable` related solution...) to share an array between processes?

Thanks,

Comment: using 'mount' I see these among others:
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755

Answer (score 4):

You may have already done this, but it is always good to confirm exactly what is failing and if the change you made took effect.  To confirm that this is really semget() returning ENOSPC, you could run it with:

`strace -ooutfile CMD`

and then look for ENOSPC in `outfile` to confirm which system call returned it.

To confirm adjusting SEMMNI and SEMMNS worked, you can:

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem`

(as [man proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) says, SEMMNI is the fourth field, SEMMNS is the second field).

---

Now, to address your question of "what else could I use?" directly, here are some choices:

- My first choice: use threads.  You don't show the code that starts other processes, but since you are sharing a Perl array between them, I suspect all processes are running the same Perl script (or the code could be written that way).  So instead of forking processes, use [threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) and use the thread locking primitives to shared the `@urls` array between threads.  I say this is my first choice because multi-threading is more commonly done with threads than with forking these days, so there are lots of great examples and the modules available have had lots of use (and they don't typically depend on Sys V interfaces).
- My second choice would be to use [File::Map](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eleont/File-Map-0.40/lib/File/Map.pm) to share the data between processes.  Again this avoids the Sys V interfaces and is likely every bit as fast as shared memory since the system will of course cache pages of the shared file in RAM (you can even ask the system to *pin* the file into RAM if you like).  Like the threads comment above, don't forget to use the appropriate locking.
- Finally, I don't see any locking calls in your code, so is it possible that you have one process generating the URLs and the other processes access the data structure read-only?  If so, another option is to feed the URLs to the sub-processes via pipes.  But based on the scale of how many URLs you typically have and if they really are read-only by the children, this idea may not apply.

Hope that gives you some viable alternatives.

Comment: thank you for this answer, it should have been accepted - threads are perfect for what I am doing, when checking all the tools available for them.